# What does it mean if one factor describes four measures, another factor describes other four measures, but both don't describe the eight measures?

Tags: r, latent-variable, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I have 8 measures: A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4. I know from the correlation matrix that they are all related. I would like to find the latent variable structure.

Using lavaan in R, I found that the first four variables (A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4) can be explained by one factor/latent variable:

```
mA <- 'fA =~ A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + A_4'
mAfit.o <- cfa(mA, data=dt)
summary(mAfit.o, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

Indeed I obtain as output that:

- Chi-Square for Test User Model is ~.6
- Comparative Fit Index (CFI), Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI) both >.095
- RMSEA < 0.05

Similarly, the second four variables (B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4) can be explained by one factor/latent variable, i.e. the model:

```
mB <- 'fB =~ B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4'
```

has low Chi-Squared, high CFI/TLI and low RMSEA. However, the following models, all have bad performance (high Chi Squared, low CLI/TLI, high RMSEA):

```
mAB1 <- 'fA =~ A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + A_4
         fB =~ B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4'

mAB2 <- 'fA =~ A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + A_4
         fB =~ B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4
         fAB =~ fA+fB'

mAB3 <- 'fAB =~ A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + A_4 + B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4'
```

How should I interpret this?